# Вызов функции при вызове иной фунции

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
public interface IMain
{
    public void Any (); 
}
public class Extra
{
    public void Extra ()
    {
        //code
    }
}
public class Child : IMain
{
    void Any ()
    {

    }
}
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы после вызова Any в классе Child вызывался метод Extra? При этом, чтобы это работало на все классы которые наследуются от IMain и это не нужно было менять в каждом дочернем объекте.

Comment: `void Any() { new Extra().Extra(); }`

Comment: Вместо интерфейса сделать абстрактный класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант через интерфейс, только для версии C# 8.0

```
public interface  IMain
{
    public virtual void Any()
    {
        new Extra().ExtraCall();
    }
}
public class Extra
{
    public void ExtraCall()
    {
        //code
    }
}
public class Child : IMain
{
}
```

Но, я вижу это немного по другому, через базовый класс. В дочерних классах вы можете переопределить базовый метод и если нужно внутри вызвать его же.

```
public class Main
    {
        public virtual void Any()
        {
            new Extra().ExtraCall();
        }
    }
    public class Extra
    {
        public void ExtraCall()
        {
            //code
        }
    }
    public class Child: Main
    {
        public override void Any()
        {
            base.Any();

            //код дополняющий метод
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Нужно лишь получить объект класса `Extra` внутри метода `Any`:

```
public class Child : IMain
{
    void Any()
    {
        var extraObj = new Extra();
        extraObj.Extra();
    }
}
```

Либо создать поле типа `Extra` в классе Child:

```
public class Child : IMain
{
    private Extra _extraObj = new Extra();
    
    void Any()
    {
        _extraObj.Extra();
    }
}
```